# Highlight an item on another div using javascript or by css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to achieve this kind of result:

[image]

I want to highlight the item in the right when I mouseover or hover on an item on the left.

How should I do that? and is it possible via javascript or jquery or css

Here is the code:

```
<div id="searchcontainer">

   <script>
   var html2;

    html2 += '<div id="rightcontainer">';
 html2 += '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png"/>';
  html2 += '<div id="imagedetail">';
   html2 += '<span class="details">Product Type</span>';
    html2 += '<span class="details">Version / Size</span>';
    html2 += '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend</span>';
    html2 += '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>';
    html2 += '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>';
    html2 += '</div>'
   html2 += '</div>';
   </script>

</div>
```

And here is my div 1

```
<div class="e-Marker"></div>
```

So imagine it **div 1** is a marker on the map and it is on ff places japan, Norway and Canada and the info of those three is on the right div displayed and I hover the marker on Japan and it will highlight the info on the right that corresponds to Japan.

Thank you (please explain it as simple as possible because I'm a beginner in javascript and jquery)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is fiddle [link - good fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/hj3sz9mo/2/)
this is easy method whenever your hover on first ul li elements it getting its index number using with `.index();` doing that we have to get reach 2nd ul li i elements with regular select `$('.second > ul > li').` `eq($(this).index())`is doing getting equality of number of first li element index

somebody try to explain with proper english thank you my english suck as cow

```js
$('.first > ul > li').mouseenter(function(){
$('.second > ul > li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('background');
}).mouseleave(function(){
$('.second > ul > li').eq($(this).index()).removeClass('background');
})
```

```css
.first,.second{
  display:inline-block;
}
li
{list-style-type: none;}
.background{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='first'>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class='second'>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is this also applicable if my container is div instead of ul li?

Comment: @Kyle if div inside ul li > yeah it will work with little bit select edition fix

Comment: actually my code structure would be like this

<div class='first'>
  <div id='anotherdiv'>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: @kyle just edit your question with your exact code structure so i can see and try to fix it for you and ask if you don't understand

Comment: unfortunately I cannot edit my question with regards to my code I have already put it there please refer to the code after the diagram plus additional info please imagine that class e-Marker works like marker of google maps so if I click it, it would display and highlight the div that has an id of 'rightcontainer' that is inside searchcontainer div

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("leftItem").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("rightItem").style.border = "2px solid red";
}
```

Or, if rightItem comes directly after leftItem, you can use pure CSS:

```
<div id="leftItem>left</div>
<div id="rightItem>right</div>

#leftItem:hover + #rightItem {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the hovered element and add a class to the corresponding element in the second div.

```js
$('#main ul li').mouseover(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('#sub ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#sub ul li').eq(index).addClass('active');
});

$('#main').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#sub ul li.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
div ul li.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="sub">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```